Vagrant box update cannot update past v12.2.0
As the title says, looking at the vagrant boxes website. The latest version of homestead is at v14.0.2
When I do vagrant box update, it would say that I'm using the latest version, but the box still stuck on php 8.1 and does not have versions beyond that.
Homestead release branch is latest
I have tried deleting the boxes but still got the same issue
Now my question is if I'm stuck on v12 how can I add newer php versions?
C:\Users\edgar\Homestead>vagrant up --provision
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: 14.0.2
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/api/v2/vagrant/laravel/homestead
The box you're attempting to add has no available version that
matches the constraints you requested. Please double-check your
settings. Also verify that if you specified version constraints,
that the provider you wish to use is available for these constraints.


I just had to update vagrant from 2.4.0 -> 2.4.1 and now it works, weird that minor version does affects things

I have V2.4.1, still facing the same issue
